# Displaying errors on the front end from my plugin

Tags: forms, errors, validation, notifications

I am creating a plugin that has a frontend form, which in turn has some validation.. Errors if validation fails and success if it passes. I have tried everything and can't get messages to appear on the frontend.

The frontend html is echoed out through a shortcode, maybe that is the cause?

```
class My_Plugin {

  private $error;

  public function __construct()
  {
    add_shortcode('my_plugin_form', array($this, 'form_shortcode'));
    add_action('init', array($this, 'form_submission'), 10, 0);
  }

  public function setError($value)
  {
    $this->error = $value;
  }

  public function getError()
  {
    return $this->error;
  }

  public function form_validation()
  {
    // do some form validation
  }

  public function form_submission()
  {
    if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['action'] == 'my_plugin_form')
    {
      if($this->form_validation() == 'passed')
      {
        // success
      }
      else
      {
        $this->setError('Form validation failed');
      }
    }
  }

  public function form_shortcode()
  {
    $err = $this->getError();

    ob_start();

    // Some HTML

    $this->getError();

    // Some more HTML

    $html = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $html;
  }
}
```

Comment: where is called "form_validation()" ?

Comment: I have improved my code.

Comment: I read the improvement but now, where is called "form_submission" ?

Comment: whoops, sorry.. updated :)

Comment: note that WordPress has an [error class](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Error). also, [this may be of interest to you](https://github.com/LucaRosaldi/wpfn-notifications).

Comment: I believe it's for the backend only, I found a way to extend it but same applies, it won't show on the front end

Comment: second link is for front end notifications, the error class works on both front and back end.

Comment: Sorry i missed that link, I have tried that as well.. followed instructions to the word nothing displays when the form is submit.